# Parametric function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function in R like this:

```
y<-function(x){2*x^2}
```

It is works for all given numbers. For example:

```
> y(2)
[1] 8
```

But it cannot return a parametric answer like:

```
 > y(a)
 [1] 2*a^2
```

How can I create a function like this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) substitute** Try `substitute`:

```
yy <-function(x) substitute(2*x^2)
yy(a)
## 2 * a^2
```

**2) S3 dispatching on x** This defines a generic `f` that uses the `substitute` if passed an object of `name` or `call` class and evaluates it numerically otherwise.

```
f <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("f")
f.name <- f.call <- function(x, ...) substitute(2*x^2, list(x = x))
f.default <- function(x, ...) 2*x^2

a <- 2
f(a)
## [1] 8

f(quote(a))   # quote(a) has name class
## 2 * a^2

f(quote(a + 1))  # quote(a + 1) has call class
## 2 * (a + 1)^2
```

**3) digits** This evaluates the argument if it only contains digits and possibly leading minus sign and otherwise performs substitution returning an expression.

```
ff <- function(x) {
   if (grepl("^-?\\d+$", deparse(substitute(x)))) 2*x^2 else substitute(2*x^2)
}

ff(2)
## [1] 8
ff(a)
## 2 * a^2
```

Note that if `a <- 2` as above but we want to evaluate it numerically we can still do it by using `do.call`:

```
a <- 2
do.call("ff", list(a))
## [1] 8
```

**4) S3 dispatching on substitute(x)**   This is like (2) but checks the class of `substitute(x)` rather than the class of `x`:

```
h <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("h", substitute(x))
h.numeric <- function(x, ...) 2*x^2
h.default <- function(x, ...) substitute(2*x^2)

h(2)
## [1] 8

h(a)
## 2 * a^2

a <- 2
do.call("h", list(a))
## [1] 8
```

Comment: Thank you! it was very helpful. Is there any way to keep the mathematical attribute of the function? Let assume g<-function(a){yy(a)} and then g(2) turn 8.

Comment: Thank you that is a genius answer but still return a text. Let `g` be a function such that `g<-function(a) {f(quote(a))}`. I would like `g(2)` turn `8` while the current code for any value of `a` always turn `2 * a^2`.

Comment: Have added (3) and (4).

Answer (score 2):

I added an `if-else` statement to your function to determine if the input object is numeric or not. If it is not numeric, it will return a character string with the expression. Otherwise, it will return the numeric output.

```
y <- function(x){

  x2 <- as.character(substitute(x))
  x3 <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x2))

  if (is.na(x3)){
    answer <- paste0("2*", x2, "^2")
  } else {
    answer <- 2*x3^2
  }
  return(answer)
}

y(2)
# [1] 8
y(a)
# [1] "2*a^2"
```